# Subclass of Marker object no longer works in v. 3.10

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an application that has worked fine for some time by creating a custom marker using this syntax:

```
MoPin.prototype = new google.maps.Marker();

function MoPin(transmitterID, position, map, title, pinColor, visible, etc,) {
this.title = title;
this.position = position;
this.visible = true;
this.status = status;
this.transmitter = transmitterID;
this.pinColor = pinColor;
etc.
```

When forced to upgrade to v. 3.10/3.11, this no longer works. It's frustrating because stepping through the script it seems that the object is created and properly populated, and the script doesn't throw an error, but when I'm done none of these custom markers display on the map.

If I substitute a regular marker (var pin = new google.maps.Marker{values}), the markers display fine.

I notice the subclass doesn't create a property "M" which is created with a regular marker.  Property "M" is an object with various properties that mean nothing to me.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: For the love of all that's Holy, is there any way to access v. 3.9 libraries?  There must be some way.